# SQL Bulk copy versus Structured Table Insert

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, bulkinsert

Just wondering if there are any performance differences between structured table inserts and bulk copy. 
Any experience or ideas which might be performant before I start implementing it. I am using Spring.net for the database layer calls.

Sql Bulk Insert

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(this.connectionstring)
{
 bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "BulkDataTable";
 bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
}
```

Sql Structured type insert
Create a data type that maps to the datatable and pass the data table with all the rows to be inserted in bulk.

```
DataTable dataTable = this.dataTableRef.Value.Clone();
// add rows the the binary data table
SqlParameter insertParam = new SqlParameter();
insertParam.ParameterName = "DataTableInput";
insertParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
insertParam.TypeName = "dbo.DataTableType";
insertParam.Value = dataTable;
insertParams.AddParameter(insertParam);
AdoTemplate.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandType.Text, "INSERT INTO <table_name> SELECT * FROM @DataTableInput", insertParams);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on how much data you want to bulk insert and how your SQL Server instance's recovery mode is set up. SqlBulkCopy can give you minimally logged inserts under some circumstances if the database is in simple or bulk recovery. There may not be much of a performance difference if the database is full recovery.

Further comparison from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx):

> Using table-valued parameters is comparable to other ways of using
> set-based variables; however, using table-valued parameters frequently
> can be faster for large data sets. Compared to bulk operations that
> have a greater startup cost than table-valued parameters, table-valued
> parameters perform well for inserting less than 1000 rows.
>
> Table-valued parameters that are reused benefit from temporary table
> caching. This table caching enables better scalability than equivalent
> BULK INSERT operations. By using small row-insert operations a small
> performance benefit might be gained by using parameter lists or
> batched statements instead of BULK INSERT operations or table-valued
> parameters. However, these methods are less convenient to program, and
> performance decreases quickly as rows increase.
>
> Table-valued parameters perform equally well or better than an equivalent parameter
> array implementation.